# Why is flink checkpoint very slow with less than 1MB state?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpoint

From HDFS path, I have seen the state each operator instance uploaded is
about 100KB, but in Flink it will cost much time, at least 1 minute per task, and totally 72 tasks. It's confirmed nothing wrong on network.But what else about other reason?

Appreciate any idea.

Comment: Is there any back-pressure happened on any task? Probably some task is a little slow, and it takes some for the following tasks to align checkpoint barriers.

Comment: @David, sorry for late to see your answer. As you said, it's due to stream process rate is slow itself so that checkpoint takes too much time?

Comment: Yes, the slow task will slow down the checkpoint, particularly for the EXACTLY_ONCE mode. Refer to the `Barrier` and `State` part of this document: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/internals/stream_checkpointing.html

Comment: @David, ok, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, @David! You should write an answer to this question.